# How do I make random.choice include not-choosing?

Tags: python, random

I try to select an item in a list randomly or not to choose anything.

For example, I want to choose 'a', or 'b', or blank(none of them).
Is there any way to do this?

Or should I just make `random.choice('a','b','')` and pop this('') out?

```
import random

foo = ['a', 'b']
print(random.choice(foo))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, maybe it can help you https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass your list to the function `random.choice` without changing it by adding the blank-choice, and remove it after, you can use this way :

```
import random

foo = ['a','b']

print(random.choice(foo+['']))

print(foo) # >>> ['a','b']
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to do this. The way you suggest (to create a new list, containing all the items of the previous list, plus an item representing None, and use `random.choice` on the new list) is a valid way to do it.

That way, for list `['a', 'b']`, you will get:

- 1/3 probability of getting `'a'`
- 1/3 probability of getting `'b'`
- 1/3 probability of getting `''` (no choice).

I would prefer to use Python's `None` to denote the absence of value.

```
my_options = ['a', 'b']
selection = random.choice(my_options + [None])
```

Alternatively, if, say you want the probability of `None` to be some value p, and then all the n choices receiving a (1-p)/n probability to be picked, you could write it like this:

```
my_options = ['a', 'b']
pnone = 0.5
if random.random() < pnone:
    selection = None
else:
    selection = random.choice(my_options)
```

If you do not care much about the probabilities, I'd choose the first way (which is what you suggested).

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying to my question!

If [None] is chosen, does [None] still have its position, right?

I mean, actually I want to insert items including none into the other list.
In that case, I tried to code like this. 

foo = ['a','b']

choice = random.choice(foo+[None])

right = ['a', 'b']

right.insert(1, choice)
print right 

Then, one of the results was ['a', None, 'b']
Here, right[1] = None, not 'b', right?

Comment: @HyunkyungKoo When you call `right.insert(1, choice)`, the value of `choice` is inserted at index 1 inside `right`, after 'a', but before 'b'. That happens no matter what value `choice` has. So the 3 possible outcomes for `right` in the end are `['a','a','b']`, `['a',b','b']` and `['a',None,'b']`. All three lists have a length of 3. In Python, a list can hold values of different types, including None values.